# How to remove Object in Java List?

Tags: java, arrays

I have one existing code, where the written line is

```
 private Rule[] ruleList;
```

Where Rule is a ***CLASS***.

I want to remove all Rules which are added here in ruleList.

but as I click right it shows like this
[image]

If it is a List, how can I delete these rules from ruleList?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to remove all items from the list? Or all items in the array from the list?

Comment: I want to remove all items from List

Comment: It's not a List but an Array. `List<Rule>` would be a List.

Comment: @Al-Jawarneh Your code does not include a `List`, instead it shows an array being used.  Is there more code we are not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

The `ruleList` is an array and not a `List`. Thus you will not find a `clear` method.

But you can use

```
Arrays.fill(ruleList, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array and not a list. Solution :

```
ruleList = new Rule[ruleList.length];
```

Comment: OP wants to delete the rules from the `ruleList` and not create a new array. Maybe because the reference to the `ruleList` has already been passed to some other object.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all items from a `List` use `clear()`

If you want to remove all items in an array from a `List` use the remove method.

**Example**

```
public class Rules {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rule[] rules = new Rule[2];
        rules[0] = new Rules.Rule();
        rules[1] = new Rules.Rule();

        //Scenario 1
        List<Rule> ruleList = new ArrayList<Rule>();
        ruleList.add(Arrays.asList(rules)); //adds array to list
        ruleList.clear(); //removes all items from List


        //Scenario2
        ruleList.add(Arrays.asList(rules)); //adds array to list
        ruleList.remove(Arrays.asList(rules));  //remove all rules in [] form list

        //Scenario3
        Arrays.fill(rules, null); //removes all elements in array
    }

    static class Rule{

    }
}
```

It is important to determine whether you are using a `List` or an `Array`.  The provided code depicts an array, however the verbiage keeps referring to a `List`.

If you actually have a `List` and want to remove all elements see Scenario 1 in the example.
If you actually have a `List` and want to remove all elements in the array from the `List` see Scenario 2 in the example.
If you actually have array and want to remove all elements from the array see Scenario 3 in the example.